# Saving inherited objects in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsuserdefaults

I am using a class which is being inherited from NSObject that is 'userDC'. This object is being saved in user defaults properly without any issue.
But now I have created one more class which is being inherited from userDC that is called 'appUserDC'.
When I try to save data in appUserDC and it's parent object it is being saved properly but when I try to save it in archive and try to retrieve it back it does not return any data which was being saved in userDC properties.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://brianflove.com/2012/10/19/nscopying-protocol/

Comment: Convert it into decodable

Comment: I am assuming you have already implemented nscopyiong protocol. If so please share class code and where you try to save it.

Comment: If you saved your object into `NSUserDefaults` successfully, your object is NSCopying compliant. Did you override `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:` and add properties to save for the subclass? What's your code for theses methods (parent class & subclass)?

Comment: mind it that this is not a preferred/recommended approach to save large data into userdefaults.

Answer (score 1):

While creating your object class using NSCopying protocol methods - 
`initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:`

From the class where you want to save the object use - `archivedDataWithRootObject` method of `NSKeyedArchiver`, this will return Data object.

After Retrieving the object, you have to unarchive that - `unarchiveObjectWithData` method of `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

Objective C example -

Class `AppuserDC`

in the implementation .m file-

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject:self.myProperty forKey:@"myProperty"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    if((self = [super initWithCoder:decoder]))
    {
        self. myProperty = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"myProperty"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

While saving your object -

```
- (void)saveMyObject:(AppuserDC *)user
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:user];
    [defaults setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:@"user"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

And retrieving object -

```
- (id)loadUserObject
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myEncodedObject = [defaults objectForKey:@"user"];

    id obj = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:myEncodedObject];
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: `if((self = [super init]))` No `[super initWithCoder:decoder]`? Especially in subclass, that could be interesting...

Comment: This is just a example, not considering superclass, but in order to access super class property that also need to have these methods implemented

Comment: But the author seems to have code working for the class of `userDC`, but have issue from its subclasses.

Comment: agreed, made adjustment :)